# Query help for voting app in Linq using SQL Server

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, linq

I'm trying to create a query to get the voting results.

There is a table which records every vote someone makes. It is possible for people to vote multiple times, but only the last vote should be taken into account.

I'm at the point that it works, except the 'only the last vote of a user should be taken into account' part.

This is my table:

**Table Vote:**

```
  id            bigint      PK
  TimeStamp     datetime
  QuestionId    int
  UserId        int
```

and the Linq query:

```
var total = (float)(_db.Votes).Count(vote => vote.Timestamp>=startWeekDay && vote.Timestamp<endWeekDay);

var results = (from vote in _db.Votes 
                  where vote.Timestamp >= startWeekDay && vote.Timestamp < endWeekDay
                  group vote by new { vote.QuestionId} into g
                  orderby g.Count() descending
                  select new VoteResults()
                      {
                          QuestionID = g.Key.QuestionId, 
                          Percentage = (g.Count() / total * 100.0f),
                      }).ToList();
```

My question: how do I change this query so that only the last cast vote per user is taken into account?

EDIT:
Given this input:

```
{
    UserId = 1,
    QuestionId = 2,
    TimeStamp = Yesterday
},
{
    UserId = 1,
    QuestionId = 1,
    TimeStamp = Today
},
{
    UserId = 2,
    QuestionId = 2,
    TimeStamp = Yesterday
},
{
    UserId = 3,
    QuestionId = 1,
    TimeStamp = Yesterday
}
```

The output should look like this:

```
{
    QuestionID = 2,
    Percentage = 33.3333
},
{
    QuestionID = 1,
    Percentage = 66.66666
}
```

Comment: download the free [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/CodeSnippetIDE.aspx) and try yourself the queries, without need to compile anything... it even uses your own EntityFramework if you want.

Comment: I know LinqPad. Thanks. It's just that I'm stuck on how to expand the query to add this extra requirement. I don't see how linqpad could help me here.

Comment: Why QuestionID = 2 and Percentage = 33.333? What should be g.Count() and Total in this case?

Comment: The g.count and total where the method I used to calculate the percentages. In the above example: 33% of the users voted question 2 and 66% voted question 1.

Comment: If you would use my old query. It g.count for questionId 2 would be 2 and the total would be 4. While in fact if you would only take the last cast vote per user into account, it should have been: g.count for questionId 2 is 1 (since the vote was overruled by a newer vote), and the total should have been 3 (since in effect only 3 valid votes are cast)

Comment: OK. I got it! :) Everything is how you look at the data. A solution is in the making...

Comment: Great! I've been trying with distinct and other operators for quite some while, but got really stuck. I'm curious to what you might come up with

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bellow I show you a test case I ran in a Console App... It should solve your problem. I tested with the data you passed in your example:

```
public class User
{
    public int UserId {get; set;}
}

public class Question
{
    public int QuestionId { get; set; }
}

public class Vote
{
    public int VoteId {get; set;}
    public DateTime TimeStamp {get; set;}
    public Question Question {get; set;}
    public User User { get; set; }
}

public class VoteResult
{
    public int QuestionId { get; set; }
    public float Percentage { get; set; }
}

public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var question1 = new Question();
        question1.QuestionId = 1;

        var question2 = new Question();
        question2.QuestionId = 2;

        var user1 = new User();
        user1.UserId = 1;

        var user2 = new User();
        user2.UserId = 2;

        var user3 = new User();
        user3.UserId = 3;

        List<Vote> votes = new List<Vote>()
        {
            new Vote()
            { 
                Question = question2,
                TimeStamp = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1), // Yesterday
                User = user1,
                VoteId = 1
            },

            new Vote()
            { 
                Question = question1,
                TimeStamp = DateTime.Today,
                User = user1,
                VoteId = 2
            },

            new Vote()
            {
                Question = question2,
                TimeStamp = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1), // Yesterday
                User = user2,
                VoteId = 3
            },

            new Vote()
            {
                Question = question1,
                TimeStamp = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1), // Yesterday
                User = user3,
                VoteId = 4
            }
        };

        // Group Votes by User and then Select only the most recent Vote of
        // each User
        var results = from vote in votes
                        where vote.TimeStamp >= DateTime.Today.AddDays(-7) &&
                              vote.TimeStamp < DateTime.Today.AddDays(1)
                        group vote by vote.User into g
                        select g.OrderByDescending(v => v.TimeStamp).First();

        // Total Users who voted
        var total = results.Count();

                               // Group Users' votes by Question
        foreach (var result in results.GroupBy(v => v.Question.QuestionId))
        {
            var voteResult = new VoteResult()
            {
                QuestionId = result.Key,
                Percentage = ((float)result.Count() / total) * 100.0f
            };

            Console.WriteLine(voteResult.QuestionId);

            Console.WriteLine(voteResult.Percentage);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Hi +Leniel Macaferi. If I read your query correct, it sorts ALL the votes per QuestionID and than takes the last one. However, it should take all votes of all users into account, but for any given user only the last one voted.

Comment: Just a moment... I'm trying a Console App and will post the result here. :)

Comment: +Leniel Macaferi Thanks for helping. I've edited my question to show example input and output.

Comment: Did you get the idea behind the solution?

Comment: +leniel macaferi I'm still in awe and absorbing it. Do I understand correct that at first you filter the whole set so that you only have the unique votes per user, and then with the second groupby you use the previous result to get the votes per question?

Comment: Yes... at first group Votes by User and select only the most recent Vote each user has cast `select g.OrderByDescending(v => v.TimeStamp).First();`. Then with the second `GroupBy` you group all the Users' votes by the Question.

Comment: great!  thanks very much!  It never occurred to me to split the problem like that.